# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniavutil in java.library.path

Tags: android, maven, opencv, intellij-idea, javacv

i got an project for android lip reading from Github but when i want to run and test it, i have this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniavutil in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:489)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:431)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.avutil.<clinit>(avutil.java:75)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.avcodec.<clinit>(avcodec.java:86)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.<init>(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:104)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.createDefault(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:75)
    at edu.lipreading.vision.AbstractFeatureExtractor.getGrabber(AbstractFeatureExtractor.java:48)
    at edu.lipreading.vision.AbstractFeatureExtractor.extract(AbstractFeatureExtractor.java:34)
    at edu.lipreading.vision.GetFileTest.readFromUrlTest(GetFileTest.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:202)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no avutil in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:481)
    ... 47 more
```

this project is maven-based and my IDE is intellij idea on windows7. 
this project uses javacv and opencv. what should i do?
i have this parts in pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.javacv</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
            <version>${javacv.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.javacv</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
            <version>${javacv.version}</version>
            <classifier>${platform.name}</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

do i should install some library? or some thing else?

Comment: moved to: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv maybe the goupId is deprecated